# Spring webflux/reactor using @Scheduled to read database and perform some tasks

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am new to spring webflux and my current spring boot application uses a scheduler(annotated as @Scheduled) to read list of data from DB, call a rest api concurrently in batches and then writes to event stream
I want to achieve the same in Spring webflux.

1. Should I use @Scheduled or use schedulePeriodically from Webflux?
2. How can I batch items from DB into smaller sets(say 10 items) and concurrently call rest api?
3. At present the app fetches max 100 records in one scheduler run and then it processes them. I am planning to shift to r2dbc, if i do so, can i limit the flow of data like 100?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1. Should I use @Scheduled or use schedulePeriodically from Webflux?**

`@Scheduled` is an annotation which is part of the spring framework scheduled package, while schedulePeriodically is a function which is part of reactor, so you can't really compare the two. I dont see any problems in using the annotation since it is part of the core framework.

**2. How can I batch items from DB into smaller sets (say 10 items) and concurrently call rest api?**

By using the `Flux#buffer` functions which will emit a list of items when the buffer is full.

```
Flux.just("1", "2", "3", "4")
        .buffer(2)
        .doOnNext(list -> {
            System.out.println(list.size());
        }).subscribe()
```

Will print 2 each time.

**3. At present the app fetches max 100 records in one scheduler run and then it processes them. I am planning to shift to r2dbc, if i do so, can i limit the flow of data like 100?**

Well you can as written before, you fetch, and then buffer the responses into lists of 100, you can then place each list in its own flux and emit items again, or process each list of 100 items. Up to you.

There are a lot of functions under the buffer segment, check them out.

[Flux#buffer](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#buffer-int-)

Comment: thanks for your response  Toerktumlare. I am worried the buffer will put everything in the memory which may result in OOM. How about limit methods? 
The code sample above does not compile as there is no method as doSuccess. (rector-core:3.3.5.RELEASE)
If I want to batch the 100 records from DB, to smaller chunks of 10 each, to be processed concurrently in separate schedulers, how can I achieve that?
The buffer(int) method returns List<List<Object>> and do I need to use backpressure in this case? or if i make my @Scheduled to run at fixed delay?

Comment: No there is isnt a function called `doSucces`. They have update the api `doOnNext`. If you have several more questions you need to start a new question. But i can tell you that why would you want to place it on 10 different schedulers? Read up on reactor and its functions before you ask such things. `flatMap` is already async so i cant see any reason as to why unleass you are doing heavy mathematical computations which then you should be using parallell flux.

Comment: I suggest you start to actually program and do some basic stuff in reactor before asking all these questions. Read the getting started with reactor in the official documentation. There it explains how you should develop to take advantage of its async abilities and it will answer most of your questions. Then after when you have development problems you can ask specific questions, with code, here.

Comment: The documentation will explain what backpressure is and when to use it and how you use it. So read the docs.

Answer (score -1):

Flux.buffer will combine the streams and will emit a list of streams of mentioned buffer size.
For batching purpose, you can use Flux.expand or Mono.expand. You only have to provide your condition in the expand to execute it again or finally end it.
Here are the examples:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("1");
        
        
        Flux.just(list)
        .buffer(2)
        .doOnNext(ls -> {
            System.out.println(ls.getClass());
            // Buffering a list returns the list of list of String
            System.out.println(ls);
        }).subscribe();
        
        Flux.just(list)
        .expand(listObj -> {
            // Condition to finally end the batch 
            if (listObj.size()>4) {
                return Flux.empty();
            }
            // Can return the size of data as much as you require
            list.add("a");
            return Flux.just(listObj);
        }).map(ls -> {
            // Here it returns list of String which was the original object type not list of list as in case of buffer
            System.out.println(ls.getClass());
            System.out.println(ls);
            return ls;
        }).subscribe();
    }


Output:

class java.util.ArrayList
[[1]]            /// Output of buffer list of list 
class java.util.ArrayList
[1]
class java.util.ArrayList
[1, a]
class java.util.ArrayList
[1, a, a]
class java.util.ArrayList
[1, a, a, a]
class java.util.ArrayList
[1, a, a, a, a]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shubham1932, sorry i saw your post late. I will try it out. Thanks