# Does @Scheduled support Project Reactor for fixedDelay with initial delay of zero?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

Similar to [Spring webflux/reactor using @Scheduled to read database and perform some tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65638710/spring-webflux-reactor-using-scheduled-to-read-database-and-perform-some-tasks) but I am asking specifically for `fixedDelay`

I know I can't just use a `Mono.subscribe()` as the delay semantics will not work.

I know I can use `Mono.delayElement` but I would prefer an annotation driven approach which also allows for `fixedDelayString` that allows for a SPeL expression.

So my question is whether it is possible for

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString="${interval}")
Mono<Void> generateKeys() {
  return ...a mono...
}
```

At the moment I am doing something like this

```java
@Service
public class JwksProvider {

  private Disposable subscription;

  private Mono<Void> doWork(Instant ignored) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(UUID::randomUUID).doOnNext(System.out::println).then();
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void start() {

    final Flux<Instant> repeat =
        Mono.fromCallable(Instant::now)
            .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .repeat()
            .doOnNext(this::doWork);
    subscription = repeat.subscribe();
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void stop() {
    subscription.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it work with the `Scheduled` annotation like so:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString="${interval}")
Disposable generateKeys() {
  return Mono.fromCallable(() -> /* do stuff */)
    .subscribe()  
}
```

Returning the `Mono` itself is not enough as a subscription is never created. Another option would be to use `block()` instead of `subscribe()`. Keep in mind that this way of doing it has some issues. If the execution of the scheduled task takes longer than the fixed interval they will end up running simultaneously. It might be better to let reactor handle the fixed interval repetitions and take advantage of the backpressure support.

```
@Bean
Disposable keyGenerator() {
  return Flux.interval(
      Duration.ofSeconds(0), // initial delay.
      Duration.ofSeconds(fixedInterval))
    .onBackpressureDrop(__ -> log.info("Skipping iteration! The previous one is still running."))
    .concatMap(__ -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> /* do stuff */), 0) // 0 limits the operator's prefetch buffer.
    .subscribe()
}
```

Comment: Is returning a Disposable from scheduled documented somewhere?

Comment: I chose delay so that it needs to complete before starting the next one.

Comment: returning the `Disposable` is not something that you would find in the documentation, it's how reactor works. The entire stream is inactive until subscribed on, and the subscription produces a `Disposable` object. Delay might not work as you expect it due to the async nature of the code. Delay will keep the stream from completing but cannot really stop a new one from starting, that's why `concatMap` is used in the example, it keeps stream values from being processed until the one currently inside `concatMap` has exited.